# Is it better filter non Null objects with map operation or return Stream.empty() on flatMap operation?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm really curious about this simple performance/best_use/best_practice related case scenario:

If I have this simple snippet:

```java
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Hello1", "Hello2", "Hello3", "Jhon", "Doe", "Hello4");
```

```java
    list.stream()
                .map(s -> {
                    if (s.contains("Hello")) {
                        return "World";
                    }
                    return null;
                })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**OR**

```java
    list.stream()
                .flatMap(s -> {
                    if (s.contains("Hello")) {
                        Stream.of("World");
                    }
                    return Stream.empty();
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**NOTE:** I know that maybe Map the `String` just to convert it to another `String` doesn't make much sense, but that is just for the example representation purposes, it could be a pojo or an integer or anything else.

Which one will perform better? or which would be the best option?

I'm trying to understand which is the better option in cases in which some conditional appears in the logic when we use streams chains.

Thank you.

Comment: One of them creates a stream instance to unpack it instantly. The other just checks for null. Which one is faster in your opinion? You should always write what is the most readable, and not nitpick for such small optimisations.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Thank you for your opinion!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't create and wrapper like another `Stream` for avoiding nulls, nor return the `null` value for non matching strings, you can simply filter the strings having `Hello` word and then use `map` for value modification

```
 list.stream()
     .filter(s->s.contains("Hello"))
     .map(s -> "world")
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Of course that's a wonderful solution. But the IF inside i'ts just for the example.. as the real situation is not that simple. there are multiple conditions and the filter in this case dont help. so.. in your opinion, based on my question, which one is better or has better readability or performance?

Comment: The least case i prefer returning `null` instead of wrapping with `Stream`, but i will mostly recommend to refactor code in real work and make it possible to just use `filter` and `map` and that's why we are here today @DanielHenao

Comment: @DanielHenao why should `filter` not help with “multiple conditions”? If you can express a logic to return `null` under those conditions, you can express the same logic to return `false`.

Comment: @Holger and @Deadpool. The reason filter doesnt help, is beacause all the registries in the `stream` at the time of the `.map()` are the ones I need, I don't need to filter anything (because everything is useful) but to choose what to transform inside the `.map()`. So even if I filter, the real case scenario is choose what to transform inside the `map`

Comment: @DanielHenao it’s not clear what “registries” is supposed to mean or why you insist on “I don't need to filter anything”, when your entire question is about filtering. Mapping to `null`, followed by `filter(Objects::nonNull)` or using `flatMap` to a stream of one or zero elements, *is* filtering.